# Light Fixtures will not work, even though I have power

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I have two pendant light fixtures in my kitchen hooked to 3-way switches. One bulb burned out and while replacing that bulb the other blew out. I've replaced both bulbs, but get nothing. I removed the fixtures from the ceiling and tested the wires and switches with a voltmeter. All good. There is power going to the ceiling boxes and the white & black wires coming from the ceiling. I bought two temporary fixtures to further test it. I have successfully tested those fixtures with the volt meter as well as the bulbs... everything. No fixtures work even though I still have power.

Somehow, once any fixture is hooked to power, it kills it. Nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: It sounds like you are either seeing phantom (induced) power, which can show on a tester but not be nearly enough to power a light, or you have a loose connection somewhere. Can you upload pictures of the switches showing all the wires connected to them?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. My voltmeter is showing 120v. My (minimal) understanding of phantom power is that its usually around 50 or so. I'm checking all connections now. If it's possible to get pix I'll do it.

Comment: Turn the breaker off and take a resistance/continuity reading from neutral to ground at the fixture box in question?  Also, do the temporary fixtures work when connected to a different circuit?

Comment: Yes. The temps work on other circuits as do the actual kitchen lights.

Comment: Any chance the neutral wire is broken?  That'll do it everytime since neutral is part of the current loop.  With a broke neutral, hot-ground will read 120V, voltage testers will light up, everything will seem peachy.  Neutral-ground will also read 120V, but nobody checks that lol.